# Get Template Name - Smarty

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I'm dealing with website is a mess and need to find out the template file that smarty is rendering.

Is there a method on the smarty template object that I can call to get the current template file?

for example

```
echo $tplObj->getTemplate(); // echos "shop/templates/cart.tpl"
```

Answer (score 12):

From the doc:

```
{$smarty.template}
```

Returns the name of the current template being processed. The following example shows the container.tpl and the included banner.tpl with {$smarty.template} within both.

```
<b>Main container is {$smarty.template}</b>
{include file='banner.tpl'}
```

will output

```
<b>Main page is container.tpl</b>
banner.tpl
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [`{debug}`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.debug.php) tag and its associated [Debugging console](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/chapter.debugging.console.php) could help, here ?